# Pandas plotting issue

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following dataframe:

```
Price,Volume
6550,18
6551,5
6552,2
6553,13
......
......
......
7001,3
7002,21
```

I want price along one axis and volume along the other. Since this is a pandas dataframe I am under the impression I can just plot it as follows:

```
df.plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

However it is plotting both columns along the same axis. I want each column on a separate axis. I have tried the following which does not work:

```
df.plot(kind='bar', xticks=df['Price'], yticks=df['Volume'])
```

Any suggestions on what i'm doing wrong would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you plot using `df.plot(kind='bar')` it will use the Index for the x-axis and then plot all columns in the DataFrame as y-values.

To get around this, [you can choose `x` and `y` values to be used](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html), such as:

```
df.plot(x='Price', y='Volume', kind='bar')
```

See [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.0/visualization.html) for more examples of plotting using `pandas`.

Answer (score 1):

Specify the x and y you desire by label:

```
df.plot(x='Price', y='Volume', kind='bar')
```

Here is the complete documentation:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html